# How do I quote a UTF-8 String Literal in Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, unicode, utf-8

I'm looking to encode and store Unicode in a Sqlite database.  Is there any way to raw encode a UTF-8 (unicode) string literal in a sql query.

I'm looking for something similar to java where I can toss a \u00E9 into a string and have it automagically upconvert to Unicode.

Comment: Are you talking about doing this in a custom app in Java, or from the SQLite command interpreter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What language are you using? SQLite handles Unicode just fine, creating the literals in your hosting language is less obvious.

```
$ sqlite3 junk.sqlite
SQLite version 3.6.22
sqlite> create table names (id integer primary key, name string);
sqlite> insert into names values (null, 
    'î℉ yõù gѷЄ ΣϘГくטƏ UTF-8, it stores it');
sqlite> select * from names;
1|î℉ yõù gѷЄ ΣϘГくטƏ UTF-8, it stores it
```

Answer (score 7):

SQLite doesn't have escape sequences.  But your programming language probably does.

```
# in Python
db.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn) VALUES('\u00E9')")
```

or

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn) VALUES(?)", ['\u00E9'])
```

If for some reason you have to write a UTF-8 literal in pure SQL, you can do something like:

```
sqlite> SELECT CAST(X'C3A9' AS TEXT);
é
```

**Edit**: Since this answer was originally written, a [CHAR](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#char) function has been added to SQLite.  So now, you could write

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn) VALUES(CHAR(233))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is reinterpretation of escape sequences in sqlite you can (ab)use json_extract eg.

```
    UPDATE  `tableToFix`  SET  `columnToFix` = json_extract('"'  ||  `columnToFix`  ||  '"', '$');
    INSERT INTO test VALUE (json_extract('"P\u0159\u00edli\u0161 \u017elu\u0165ou\u010dk\u00fd k\u016f\u0148 \u00fap\u011bl \u010f\u00e1belsk\u00e9 \u00f3dy."', '$'));
```

Notice: quotes handling. Valid json string starts and ends with " so you must add them before use of json_extract

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your database to use UTF-8 (I believe this is default for many installations; do `PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";` at schema creation time to be certain), this shouldn't be an issue.

If you send SQLite3 a set of characters encoded in UTF-8, it should have no problem dealing with it.

If Java has the ability to allow you to "toss a \u0039 into a string", I'd just use that, and ensure that when you try to place the string into the database, that you have the string convert to a UTF-8 byte encoding using whatever mechanism Java provides.  I do not believe SQLite provides or needs to provide this for you.

Comment: Why would you "toss a \u0039 into a string"?  Seems it'd be a whole lot easier just to write "9".