# Why do I have to re-encode to utf-8 my encoded JSON response in order to save it to SQLite?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, encoding, utf-8

I get my JSON response properly encoded with UTF-8 and I try to save the string of response into my SQLite table.

Then I noticed that it is not properly saved and has ????? characters when not english.

I tried to fix encoding before saving

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            SavedResponse mysavedresponse = new SavedResponse();
            JSONObject j = null;
            int resp_count = (int) db.getResponsesCount();

            try {

                //String MyResponse = fixEncodingUnicode(response);
                //CHECK IF IT IS NEW RESPONSE
                if(resp_count>0)
                {
                    mysavedresponse = db.getMySavedResponse();
                    response = mysavedresponse.getSavedresponse();

                }else
                {
                    **db.AddResponse(fixEncodingUnicode(response));**
                    db.close();
                }

                j = new JSONObject(response);




            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Additionally, If  I add db.deleteresponses initialy **then its working** if I comment out the db.deleteresponses I get again ??????.

Why if my response is properly encoded I can see it on debug, it is messed up when it is saved in sqlite table?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444335/how-do-i-quote-a-utf-8-string-literal-in-sqlite3

Comment: Nobody knows if your JSON really is encoded correctly, or what your `fixEncodingUnicode` does.

Comment: I checked it , it looks ok , and its a valid json

Answer (score -1):

Does your JSON object need to be stored exactly as JSON in SQLite? It would be easier to just base64 encode it, since you don't have to worry about character set clashes then with all the characters encoded in ASCII.